# Ubuntu One, failure: DOES_NOT_EXIST, high CPU usage, no syncing

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, sync

over the weekend I updated my computer to Windows 8. So far Ubuntu One was running smoothly, but ever since the update (clean, new install) Ubuntu doesn't sync any more.

In Windows 7 it would start to sync at full internet speed as soon as I drop a file. But now in Windows 8, as soon as I drop a new file into the Ubuntu One folder, CPU usage goes up to about 50 % and no network traffic occurs. This stays like that for a couple of minutes, CPU usage goes back to normal and then the client says that all is in sync - which isn't true.

Is it too early for Windows 8? Do others have the same problem or is there something I can do about it?

I tried a couple of different things, and realized that if the file size is 20 MB the files do get uploaded (It didn't work with 200, 100 and 50 MB large files) But even with 20 MB large files, the upload is very slow and not steady. Also, not all files get uploaded, only about 10 %.

Here's [a link](http://pastebin.com/Z1V07Nsd) to the relevant part of the log, when I try to upload one single large file(~1 GiB).

I don't really understand the log. It seems to start the upload but then stops with: failure: DOES_NOT_EXIST, but the file is certainly there.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
-Peter

Comment: just fyi, https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-versions-of-windows-are-supported/ doesn't say they support Win8 yet, but that may be because the page hasn't been updated?